# Question regarding complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

Let's say I have a function  z = 1 + $\sqrt{3}i$ .

I am looking to find r and θ such that z= $re^{iθ}$

How would I solve this problem?

My attempt is as follows:

1 = Re(z)

$\sqrt{3}i$  = Im(z)

r = |z| = |1+$\sqrt{3}$i| = $\sqrt{1^{2} + \sqrt{3}^2}$ = 2

θ = $cos^{-1}$$({1/2})$ = ${π/3}$

So, my answer would be $2e^{π/3i}$

Any further explanations / how to tackle this problem would be helpful!

Comment: That looks about right. (Note that you can add any integer multiple of $2\pi$ to $\theta$.) How is this an ODE question though?

Comment: @Tunococ because it's a question from the 2nd ODE chapter in the book. It's introducing Euler's formula

Comment: I see. I asked only because this question deals only with the elementary theory of complex numbers and no derivatives or differential equations. The tag "differential-equations" seems a little less useful than "complex-numbers".

Comment: Please edit the title also since this is not a `ode` or `euler-method` question at heat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Euler's Identity:

$$ r{\rm e}^{{\bf i}\theta} = r\cos \theta + {\bf i} r \sin \theta $$

$$\begin{align} r \cos\theta & = 1 \\
r \sin \theta &= \sqrt{3} \end{align} $$

Square both equations and add them to get

$$ r^2 (\cos^2 \theta+ \sin^2 \theta) = 1^2 + \sqrt{3}^2 \\ r^2 = 4 \\ r = 2 $$

Divide them to get

$$ \tan \theta = \frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{1} = \sqrt{3}  \\ \theta = \frac{\pi}{3} = 60°$$